# stack labels on bar chart displayed only after resizing window

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart in JSFiddle with the below link:

https://jsfiddle.net/aditya14641/hLtj3wqb/286/

```
stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          var sum = 0;
          var series = this.axis.series;
          for (var i in series) {
            sum += Math.abs(series[i].yData[this.x]);
          }
          if (sum < 0 && this.isNegative || sum >= 0 && !this.isNegative)
            return sum;
        }
      }
```

I see that the stack labels I am displaying on drilldown of chart for each bar are not visible unless I resize the JSFiddle window. Also, the labels are shown not at correct positions:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a **bug**. I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8501

**Workaround:**

Set second argument (redraw) of `setCategories` to `false`:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['20-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60']);
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zh7qfes1/